# I did "hg update -C" and now nothing is working anymore

Tags: python, django

I did `hg update -C` on prod server and nothing working anymore. TemplateDoesNotExist, Database Column Does Not exist and all possible error messages.. what did I do wrong?

Comment: please tell me why before closing it

Comment: There's very little information in your question don't you think? To answer "what did I do wrong", I'd need to have psychic powers straight out of an X-Men movie. Does this work on your dev machine? Are you managing the database migrations? Are you coding on Windows and deploying on Linux? Throw us a bone!

Comment: @MrE, this is all what i know. I committed, pushed and pulled in server and hg update -C, bum everything is gone. wsgi.py is still ok, i dont know what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely one of the changes added a new model or changed an existing model to cause the Database Column Does Not Exist error.

As for the TemplateNotFound exception: someone forgot to add a new template file to the repository and as such you can't find it now.

Ask your coworkers/co-developers or check the repo logs on who changed something.

If you want a more detailed answer please give more information.

Comment: what does ``hg update -C`` do? before this, everything worked fine, i always did ``hg update``.

Comment: With the -C/--clean option, uncommitted changes are discarded and the working directory is updated to the requested changeset. Source: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update
But the problems appears to me like someone committing incomplete updates.